# How to free memory after strdup?

Tags: c++, memory

I have such class:

```
class Kot{
public:
    string name;
};
```

I create an instance of it:

```
Kot* kot = new Kot;
kot->name = "John";
```

Then I want to create a duplicate of string:

```
string name;
name = strdup(kot->name.c_str());
```

I use `strdup` because I want to `delete kot` and use only `name` variable`.
But I have a 5 bytes memory leak due to`name`memory allocation.
How can I free it safely? I tried to do`delete &name`, but I have:

```
Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)
```

Comment: Do not use strdup if you are writing c++ code, instead just assign to a new string  i.e. `name = kot->name;` then you get a copy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably detected a 5-byte memory leak, but it is not because of the `string`.

Each call to `strdup` creates a new `char[]` of the size matching the length of the string. You should bind it to a raw pointer `char*` and remove it at some point.

What you did instead, is that you create a *temporary* `char*` pointer. Let's call it `temp` for our purposes.
The `temp` string is then passed to `std::string`'s constructor. The `std::string` makes *another* copy of it, leaving the original `temp` intact.

Then the `temp` pointer just dissapears, without properly clearing the memory.

At the end, when the `std::string` object is destroyed, it properly clears its own, private copy of the string. But the memory previously pointed by `temp` is never freed.

A quick fix would be to:

```
char* temp = strdup(kot->name.c_str());
name = temp;
free(temp);
```

However, you don't even have to do that! If you assign one `std::string` object to another, you make a proper copy of its contents already. So:

```
name = kot->name;
```

will most likely do exactly what you are trying to achieve already -- making a copy of `kot->name` within your `name`. In such scenario, `name` and `kot->name` become two completely separate strings with the same (copied) content. From that point onward, changing/deleting one does not affect the other.

Comment: `name = kot->name;` it is bad advise because I want to `delete kot` and use only name variable. So must I use strdup in such case?

Comment: @RomaKarageorgievich: You can `delete kot` without affecting the assigned `name`. C++ strings are proper classes which manage their own memory. In particular, the assignment `name=kot->name` will make a *new* copy of the text, completely independent from the one stored in `kot->name`.

Answer (score 4):

You use `free()`, not `delete`.

Per [the standard documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strdup.html):

> The strdup() function shall return a pointer to a new string, which is
>   a duplicate of the string pointed to by s. The returned pointer can be
>   passed to `free()`. A null pointer is returned if the new string
>   cannot be created.

Comment: @RomaKarageorgievich *free(&name) also gives me an error.*  And what is `&name`?  `&name` is not the value returned from `strdup()`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a memory leak here:

```
name = strdup(kot->name.c_str());
```

because you never release memory allocated by `strdup`.

To avoid this problem you can simply construct `name` from the `kot->name`:

```
name = kot->name;
```

Comment: nope, I want to have exactly a duplicate of `kot->name` string.

Comment: @RomaKarageorgievich What is an exact duplicate in your understanding?

Comment: @Roma Karageorgievich: But "exact duplicate" is exactly what `name = kot->name` creates. Your `strdup` does not change anything in that regard, besides creating a memory leak.

Comment: If you really want exact duplicate, then you should use
`name = std::move(kot->name);`

This only works if you discard `kot`, as `kot->name` will contain undefined string.